# How to simulate a multivariate Logistic-Normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, text-mining, logit, dirichlet-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm trying to generate a text document using reverse ["Correlated Topic Models"](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiLafferty2006.pdf), which is an advanced version of LDA ([Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf)).
In this version the topics are generated over a multinomial distribution with a Logistic-Normal prior.
This allows adding correlation between topics through the covariance matrix.

Can anyone please help me simulate values from a multivariate Logistic-Normal distirubtion, i.e. given input parameters myu, sigma (mean vector, and covariance matrix respectively), the result is a distribution over topics.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `scipy.stats` doesn't provide the logistic normal distribution. However, you could draw random samples from a multivariate normal distribution (e.g. using `numpy`) and transform them with a logistic transformation to simulate samples drawn from the logistic-normal distribution.

Let's assume your probability vectors are $D=3$ dimensional.

```
import numpy as np

# draw from multivariate random distribution of dimension D-1 = 2
mean = (1, 2)
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov)
```

Now (as you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution#Multivariate_generalization)), you can transform your normally distributed sample $y \in \mathcal{S}^{D-1}$ to a logistic-normally distributed sample $x \in \mathcal{S}^{D}$:

$$
\mathbf{y} = \left[ \log \left( \frac{ x_1 }{ x_D } \right) , \dots , \log \left( \frac{ x_{D-1} }{ x_D } \right) \right]
$$

$$
\mathbf{x} = \left[ \frac{ e^{ y_1 } }{ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} e^{ y_i } } , \dots , \frac{ e^{ y_{D-1} } }{ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} e^{ y_i } } , \frac{ 1 }{ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} e^{ y_i } } \right]
$$